# Convert GWT xml.client.Document to XML string

Tags: java, xml, dom, gwt

I have a `com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document` object I used `XMLParser.parse(...)` to create. I would like to serialize it back to the XML string from which it was derived. What is the easiest way to do this? I don't see a straightforward way from reading the Javadocs on this and related classes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

-tjw

Comment: Agreed.  Javadocs are not clear.  http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html  All it says about toString() is that it's inherited from JavaScriptObject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
document.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're fine with going for an external lib, **XStream** is the best bet. Have a look at this [two-minute tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html#to-xml)

Comment: I know about XStream, it is built for serializing arbitrary Java objects. This is a `Document` object, which represents XML one-to-one already, like the DOM. Also, XStream must be compatible with GWT's deferred binding to convert the Java code to Javascript. This is not the solution I'm looking for.